# Tax_query not working in wordpress. how to solve?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made a page template where i can filter some posts. If u do a normal WP_Query everything is fine. But if i use the tax_query it displays no posts.

for registering the post types and taxonomies i use the plugin 'cptui'.

The regular WP_Query request:

```php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => $post->post_name,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => $paged,
                                    
));

if(!$_POST) { //If not filtered ... then show all
    if($query->have_posts()): while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        echo "<a href='".get_post_permalink()."'><div style='box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05); padding: 50px; width: 100%; margin: 5px; '>";
        echo "<h5>" . $query->post->post_title . "</h5>";
        echo "<p>" . get_field( "plaats" ) . '-' . get_term(get_field('dienstverbanden'))->name . "</p>";
        echo "</div></a>";
    endwhile; endif;
}
```

I read other posts and they said i could use the `php echo $GLOBALS['query']->request;`  to see what the mysql query is.

My query is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'vacature' 
  AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 6, 6
```

and now the request with the tax_query.

The tax_query WP_Query request:

```php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => $post->post_name,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
           'taxonomy' => 'provincie',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'noord-brabant',
            'include_children'  => 0
        ),
    ),
));

if(!$_POST) { //If not filtered ... then show all
    if($query->have_posts()): while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        echo "<a href='".get_post_permalink()."'><div style='box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05); padding: 50px; width: 100%; margin: 5px; '>";
        echo "<h5>" . $query->post->post_title . "</h5>";
        echo "<p>" . get_field( "plaats" ) . '-' . get_term(get_field('dienstverbanden'))->name . "</p>";
        echo "</div></a>";
    endwhile; endif;
}
```

The query I get now is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (3)) 
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'vacature' 
  AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 6, 6
```

and I get no posts back.

Do you know any solution for this?

Full code of the template:

```php
<div id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php   
                                global $post;  

                                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                                $query = new WP_Query(array(
                                    'post_type' => $post->post_name,
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 6,
                                    'paged' => $paged,
                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'provincie',
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' => array( 'noord-brabant')
                                        )
                                    )
                                ));

                                // echo $GLOBALS['query']->request;

                                if(!$_POST) { //If not filtered ... then show all
                                    if($query->have_posts()): while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                                        echo "<a href='".get_post_permalink()."'><div style='box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05); padding: 50px; width: 100%; margin: 5px; '>";
                                        echo "<h5>" . $query->post->post_title . "</h5>";
                                        echo "<p>" . get_field( "plaats" ) . '-' . get_term(get_field('dienstverbanden'))->name . "</p>";
                                        echo "</div></a>";
                                    endwhile; endif;
                                }
                                else { //now its filtered
                                    $null = true;
                                    if($query->have_posts()): while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

                                        $filterconditions = []; //hier komen alle filtercondities in
                                    
                                        $keys = array_keys($_POST);
                                        foreach($keys as $key) {
                                            if($_POST[$key] == "on") {
                                                $filter = explode("_",$key);
                                                $field = $filter[0];
                                                $filter = $filter[1];
                                                
                                                $taxonomy = get_field( $field );
                                                $term = get_term_by('term_id', $taxonomy, $field);
                                                array_push($filterconditions, '"' . $filter . '"' . '==' . '"' . $term->name . '"');
                                            }
                                        };

                                        $filterconditions = implode('&&', $filterconditions);
                                        // echo $filterconditions;
                                        if(eval("return $filterconditions;")) {
                                            $null = false;
                                            echo "<a href='".get_post_permalink()."'><div style='box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05); padding: 50px; width: 100%; margin: 5px; '>";
                                            echo "<h5>" . $query->post->post_title . "</h5>";
                                            echo "<p>" . get_field( "plaats" ) . '-' . get_term(get_field('dienstverbanden'))->name . "</p>";
                                            echo "</div></a>";
                                        }
                                    endwhile; endif;
                                    if($null) {
                                        echo "Sorry, er zijn geen vacatures gevonden met deze filters";
                                    }
                                }

                                $total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;
                                if ($total_pages > 1 && !$null) {
                                    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
                                    echo paginate_links(array(
                                        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                                        'format' => '/page/%#%',
                                        'current' => $current_page,
                                        'total' => $total_pages,
                                        'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
                                        'next_text'    => __('next »'),
                                    ));
                                } 

                                wp_reset_query();
                            ?>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$args=array(
'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => 6,
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'provincie',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => array( 'noord-brabant')
)
)
);

$result = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $result->have_posts() )  {
while ( $result->have_posts() ) {
$result->the_post();

// this is your loop

}

} else {
// nothing
}
```

Can try above code

Comment: thanks for helping but it didn't solve it for me. i tried the array() on the terms and took your loop. It still resulted in no posts.

Comment: what is you post_type name ? $post->post_name what can you get for this variable ? can print it

Comment: 'vacature'. thats dutch for job offer

Comment: Can you pass vacature static and check !

Comment: you can get the $post->post_name by adding `global $post;` in the template

Comment: 'include_children'  => 0 works ? can comment it for moment

Comment: i tried it static but it still doesn't work. i used the $post->post_name in the regular wpquery asswel and it worked there. only if i added the tax_query it didn't so i expected this outcome.

Comment: i added 'include_children' => 0 to the code and it still doesn't work. i also removed it and it doens't work too

Answer (score 0):

You can get simple custom post type list using below code:

```
$args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 6, 
        'orderby’ => 'title', 
        'order’ => 'ASC', 
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        print the_title(); 
        the_excerpt(); 
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Place your custom post type name to retrieve post and change the while loop according to your need

Comment: I can get a simple post. thats not what its about. if i use the wpquery without the tax_query it works fine. but if i use the tax_query it will not show any posts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok can you use get post method instead of WP Query:

```
$posts_array = get_posts(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'post_type' => $post->post_name, // Get POST TYPE FROM $GLOBAL POST
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'provincie',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'noord-brabant',
          )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I get array(0) { } back in this request

Comment: without the tax_query i get my posts back